# MySQL: Select in three tables

Tags: mysql, if-statement

I am working on a system where some couriers may request their preferred tours. If there is more than one employee who requests a particular tour, I want to give it to the one who started working for us first. I want to show a smilie or something else on the overview page like this

1. Tour available
2. You would kick somebody out
3. Already requested by somebody who started first

I tried it for several hours, but I can not get the MySQL code for it.
I have 3 relevant tables.

1. Employees:

   - employeeid
   - date of entry
   - ...
2. Tours

   - tourid
   - details...
3. Requests

   - employee-id
   - tourid

I would want to select all tours including their details -> easy

I want to (at least) add another field counting the requests on that tour for further queries. I guess I need a select with the `tourid` from the 1. query

The best would be a query including an if-else statement with the result, that the field behind the `tourid` would be NULL if the tour is available or showing the date of entry of the oldest employee who requested the tour if the requestcount > 0

I am very thankful for any advice on that!

Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> 2)I want to (at least) add another field counting the requests on that
>   tour for further queries. I guess I need a select with the tourid from
>   the 1.

```
SELECT R.tourid, COUNT(R.tourid)
FROM Requests R
GROUP BY R.tourid;
```

Adding a field to track aggregate information would make things significantly more complicated (requiring e.g. triggers), and would, in principle, be premature optimisation.

> 3) Optimum would be a query including an if-else statement with the
>   result, that the field behind the tourid would be NULL if the tour is
>   available or showing the date of entry of the oldest employee who
>   requested the tour if the requestcount > 0

```
SELECT T.tourid, RE.min_date_of_entry
FROM Tours T
LEFT OUTER JOIN (
    SELECT R.tourid, MIN(E.date_of_entry) AS min_date_of_entry
    FROM Requests R
    INNER JOIN Employees E ON E.employeeid = R.employeeid
    GROUP BY R.tourid
    ) RE ON RE.tourid = T.tourid;
```

When writing SQL, you should, wherever possible, use relational logic operators such as joins instead of imperative tools like conditionals. In this case, `LEFT OUTER JOIN` will result in `NULL` values in any column taken from `RE` whenever there is no match in `RE` (`INNER JOIN`, on the other hand, will skip rows if there is no match). Note that if you plan to use the minimum date of entry to figure out the requesting employee you will have to deal with corner cases. For instance, what should happen if there are employees with the same entry date?

Comment: Thank you very much! This is what I was looking for to put everything in one query. It is working. I will try to understand what we are doing here... :) 

If the date is equal the older one gets the tour....

Answer (score 0):

To select all tours including their details you simply do

```
Select * from Tours;
```

Now you can add a field to Tours table called `count`, that keeps track of all incoming requests for that particular tourID.
Preferably, keep a trigger that updates the value of count whenever a change is made in the Request table ie., if a new request is made, or an old one is modified/deleted.

Or, you could choose to not store the value, and instead do

```
Select count(employeeID) from Requests, Tours where Requests.tourID = Tours.tourID;
```

Now for each of these employees, you want to get the earliest joining date.

```
Select min(date_of_entry) from Employees where employeeID in (Select count(employeeID) from Requests, Tours where Requests.tourID = Tours.tourID);
```

I did not understand what you meant by "field behind the tourid", but I hope this at least partially answers your query.